# How to do a spacy sentiment analysis for more than two categories

Tags: python, spacy

I am quite new to spacy and python programming. I'm trying to classify some comments into positive, negative or neutral. How do I go about doing it for 3 categories? Saw this code online but it seems to be for 2 categories - positive or negative only since boolean:

```
def load_data(limit=0, split=0.8):
    train_data=train
    # Shuffle the data
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    texts, labels = zip(*train_data)
    # get the categories for each review
    cats = [{"POSITIVE": bool(y), "NEGATIVE": not bool(y)} for y in labels]

    # Splitting the training and evaluation data
    split = int(len(train_data) * split)
    return (texts[:split], cats[:split]), (texts[split:], cats[split:])

n_texts=23486

# Calling the load_data() function 
(train_texts, train_cats), (dev_texts, dev_cats) = load_data(limit=n_texts)

# Processing the final format of training data
train_data = list(zip(train_texts,[{'cats': cats} for cats in train_cats]))
train_data[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually Sentiments are From -1 to +1 Where -1 to >0 are Negative Sentences. <0 and Up to +1 Or 1 are Positive Sentences and 0 are Neutral Sentences. You can Use Textblob Library to Apply Sentiment Analysis on Sentences. It Quiet easy to Apply Sentiment Analysis on Sentence using TextBlob Library .. I recently created a Streamlit Library that Uses Textblob library To Do the Same .. You can Go through the App and Code here.

https://share.streamlit.io/arkalsekar/sentiments-analyser/main/app.py